# Flot charting library: the last point line

Tags: jquery-plugins

I user jquery "flotcharts" library and i have a problem, the line links between the points  acting strangely in "the last" and "the before last" points, it not links between them but links the last point with the first point While it not do that "work correctly with the other points", what is the reason ?

Comment: I discovered the problem reason, it's because if not ordering the dataGraph array.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem reason, it's because if not ordering the dataGraph array.